# How to find count of tags in HTML

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an html that looks like this:

```
 <h3>First</h3>
<ol>
    <li>
        First list

        <ol>
            <li>First Sub list</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
<h3>Second</h3>
<ol>
    <li>
        second list
        <ol>
            <li>First Sub list</li>
            <li>second sub list</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        second in second list
        <ol>
            <li>First Sub list</li>
            <li>second sub list</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I need to be able to get count of li tags that appear within ol tag after each h3. So the result will
1
2

I am using this statement to calculate count

```
print(len(h3_soup1.find_next("ol").find_all("li")))
```

But this gives me count of all the li tags within ol tag. For instance for the first one it says 2 and for 2nd it says 6.

Edit:

[image: Tags to be counted]

For the first ol output should be 1
For second ol it should be 2
So print for each ol

Edit:

The final goal is to find length of these li tags. And if this length is greater than a certain number then remove the last tags. For instance if length shouldn't be greater than 1 then the second list will become:

```
<h3>First</h3>
<ol>
    <li>
        First list

        <ol>
            <li>First Sub list</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
<h3>Second</h3>
<ol>
    <li>
        second list
        <ol>
            <li>First Sub list</li>
            <li>second sub list</li>
        </ol>
    </li>

</ol>
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want. What tags would it be with your provided example?

Comment: Yes, it is unclear what you want to be counted and what not. Please add indentation to your HTML and mark which `li` tags you want to be counted.

Comment: length of first child of ol. With the example it gives tags within li as well. Just need length of outermost lis

Comment: @hannahmontanna What would be the provided output? what would be the tag's *text*?

Comment: @MendelG I have indented it and added what to be counted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter `ol.children`.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''\
<h3>First</h3>
<ol>
    <li>
        First list

        <ol>
            <li>First Sub list</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
<h3>Second</h3>
<ol>
    <li>
        second list
        <ol>
            <li>First Sub list</li>
            <li>second sub list</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        second in second list
        <ol>
            <li>First Sub list</li>
            <li>second sub list</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for ol in soup.select('h3 + ol'):
    print(
        len([e for e in ol.children
             if type(e) == type(ol) and e.name == 'li']))
```

Comment: what is the intuition behind type(e) == type(o)

Comment: `ol.children` includes NavigableString instances which we want to ignore. The `type(...)` calls are because I was too lazy to add an import for the relevant type. I could just as easily have used `has_attr(...)` to check if the `.name` property is present.